# How to find preceding label with Cleartool

Tags: command-line, clearcase, label, cleartool

I'm trying to compare files between two labels with cleartool but I can't seem to figure out how to find the preceding label to the label given.

As for now my command looks like this

```
cleartool find . -element "{lbtype_sub(TEST_APP_123456-80_1.1.C.004) && 
lbtype_sub(TEST_APP_123456-80_1.1.C.005)}" -type f 
-ver "{lbtype(TEST_APP_123456-80_1.1.C.004) && !lbtype(TEST_APP_123456-80_1.1.C.005)}" 
-exec "cmd /c copy %CLEARCASE_PN% C:\diff"
```

In this case the preceding label is provided but it would be nice if cleartool could find it by itself by just providing the latest label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A label can be applied, and even moved to any version.

Unless you are talking about **UCM baselines** (in which case a "cleartool diffbl -pred a_BASELINE@\apvob" can give you the previous baseline, from which the label is named after), you cannot find the previous label.

All you can do is to walk back from the version referenced by a label until you find another (previous) version with another label.

Answer (score 0):

Create two views and compare the views with the tool of your choice.